# Adding Columns in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to add columns together to get a total at the end of each column, I searched this topic and tried to do what it said but got the an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT SUM(Sea) FROM PlayerStats; FROM SeasonStats WHERE
>   SeasonStats.PlayerID=' at line 2

I am pretty new at this and cannot seem to figure out how to make it work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$oPlayerStats = mysql_query("
SELECT SeasonStats.Sea, SeasonStats.Team, SeasonStats.GP, SeasonStats.Goals,     SeasonStats.Assists, SeasonStats.Points, SeasonStats.PlusMinus, SeasonStats.Pim,   SeasonStats.PP, SeasonStats.SH, SeasonStats.GW, SeasonStats.GT, SeasonStats.S
SELECT SUM(Sea) FROM PlayerStats;
FROM SeasonStats
WHERE SeasonStats.PlayerID=$iPlayerID
ORDER BY SeasonStats.Sea;
") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<br><br><table border=1 cellpadding=1>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Season</td> ";
echo "<td>Team</td> ";
echo "<td>GP</td> ";
echo "<td>G</td> ";
echo "<td>A</td> ";
echo "<td>P</td> ";
echo "<td>PIM</td> ";
echo "<td>+/-</td> ";
echo "<td>PPG</td> ";
echo "<td>SHG</td> ";
echo "<td>GWG</td> ";
echo "<td>GTG</td> ";
echo "<td>Shots</td> ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oPlayerStats))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['Sea']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Team']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['GP']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Goals']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Assists']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Points']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Pim']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['PlusMinus']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['PP']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['SH']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['GW']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['GT']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['S']."</td> ";
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(Sea) AS value_sum FROM codes'); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    $sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

Comment: Just to be clear I want to add columns like GP, Goals, Assits etc.

Comment: Your title says that you want to compute a total for a particular quantity in php, but rather your example show you trying to do this in SQL with a faulty SQL query. I think your question should be why the query throws an error

Comment: Your immediate problem that causes error you mentioned is that you put `SELECT SUM(Sea) FROM PlayerStats;` in the middle of your first query. Just remove it. Now if you want MySql solution to your problem you have to post your table schemas for both tables, sample data and desired output based on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your DB schema is like, but you may want to modify your original query like this:

```
SELECT SeasonStats.Sea, SeasonStats.Team, SeasonStats.GP, SeasonStats.Goals,
SeasonStats.Assists, SeasonStats.Points, SeasonStats.PlusMinus, SeasonStats.Pim,
SeasonStats.PP, SeasonStats.SH, SeasonStats.GW, SeasonStats.GT, SeasonStats.S,
SUM(SeasonStats.Sea) as total    
FROM PlayerStats
   INNER JOIN SeasonStats ON PlayerStats.PlayerID = SeasonStats.PlayerID
WHERE SeasonStats.PlayerID = $iPlayerID
ORDER BY SeasonStats.Sea;
```

You may also want to total some columns in SQL using the `GROUP BY` CLAUSE.

Answer (score 0):

You got your summary query mixed in the rows-fetching query. You need to remove that line - the first query should be just:

```
SELECT SeasonStats.Sea, SeasonStats.Team, SeasonStats.GP, SeasonStats.Goals,
    SeasonStats.Assists, SeasonStats.Points, SeasonStats.PlusMinus,
    SeasonStats.Pim,   SeasonStats.PP, SeasonStats.SH, SeasonStats.GW,
    SeasonStats.GT, SeasonStats.S
FROM SeasonStats
WHERE SeasonStats.PlayerID=$iPlayerID
ORDER BY SeasonStats.Sea;
```